# How to change the DevExpressGrid.CustomizationForm location

Tags: c#, devexpress

I have a DevExpress grid with Column chooser. I want to show the Column chooser on Top Right corner. I have tried with:

```
Gridview1.CustomizationForm.Location.Y = 0;
```

but its not allowing me. Please suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change `Gridview1.CustomizationForm.Location.Y` directly. If you want to change location, you should use variable of `Point` type.
Here is example:

```cs
Point location = Gridview1.CustomizationForm.Location;
location.Y = 0;
Gridview1.CustomizationForm.Location = location;
```